# Text to Speech (TTS) in background task in windows phone 8/8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement a background task in my windows phone app. I need to implement TTS in my task and I don't see it working with TTS. Below is my code snippet.

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        //Some logic here
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("My message from back ground task!");    
    }
```

If I just replace the TTS with a toast message, I can see the toast message in the set interval. I also added the ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION capability to the main application. How can I implement TTS in my background scheduled task (I am trying to implement periodic task). Can some one point me to a sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Text to speech is only available to the foreground app.
Background tasks can't do any UI other than toast and tile notifications.